# Grouping 2 dictionaries in to an Array present in an Array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift

When my numbers array is like -> `["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]`

```
let numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
let chunkSize = 2
let chunks = stride(from: 0, to: numbers.count, by: chunkSize).map {
    Array(numbers[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, numbers.count)])
}

// prints as [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"], ["7"]]
```

But when my number array is like

```
   (
        {
        "facility_id" = 1;
        "options_id" = 3;
    },
        {
        "facility_id" = 3;
        "options_id" = 12;
    },
        {
        "facility_id" = 2;
        "options_id" = 7;
    },
        {
        "facility_id" = 3;
        "options_id" = 12;
    },
        {
        "facility_id" = 2;
        "options_id" = 6;
    },
        {
        "facility_id" = 1;
        "options_id" = 4;
    }
  )
```

it is is showing this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'CountableRange' to expected argument type 'Int'

Comment: What is your expected result when you changed numbers array to [{'id':1},{'id':2},{'id':3},{'id':4},{'id':5},{'id':6},{'id':7}]?

Comment: [ [{ }, { }], [{ }, { }], [{ }, { }], [{ }, { }] ]

Comment: well `["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]` is String array and `[{'id':1}]` is [[string:Int]] array

Comment: @NeerajSonaro like this: [[["id": 1], ["id": 2]], [["id": 3], ["id": 4]], [["id": 5], ["id": 6]], [["id": 7]]]?

Comment: So how can i acheive this result..can you suggest please.

Comment: I don't understand, if that is a dictionary, it is working fine with above code for me. I don't think the issue you mentioned is in above code. Try this as numbers in above code `let numbers = [["id": 1], ["id": 2], ["id": 3], ["id": 4], ["id": 5], ["id": 6], ["id": 7]]` That is how dictionary is represented in Swift.

Comment: @NeerajSonaro, and what you expect to see in result when your `numbers` is array of dictionaries?

Comment: (
      [  {
        "facility_id" = 1;
        "options_id" = 3;
    } ,
     {
        "facility_id" = 3;
        "options_id" = 12;
    } ] ,
       [ {
        "facility_id" = 2;
        "options_id" = 7;
    },
      {
        "facility_id" = 3;
        "options_id" = 12;
    }] ,
       [ {
        "facility_id" = 2;
        "options_id" = 6;
    },
        {
        "facility_id" = 1;
        "options_id" = 4;
    }]
  )

Comment: @pacification like this

Comment: @NeerajSonaro, update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct. Problem is with your input array. From one of your comment

> @adev -> var dataArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray.init() –

you are using `NSMutableArray`, not swift `Array`. NSMutableArray cannot be subscripted using a `CountableRange<Int>`

```
$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, numbers.count)  //returns CountableRange<Int>
```

You need to use swift `Array` to make this work

Comment: @NeerajSonaro, Glad to see that my comment helped. I was thinking the same.

Answer (score 1):

If this piece of code

> `[{'id':1},{'id':2},{'id':3},{'id':4},{'id':5},{'id':6},{'id':7}]`

is `Dictionary`, then your strategy should be like:

1. get all values into a plain array;
2. use values in you stride as you did.

Example:

```
let dict = [["id": 1], ["id": 2], ["id": 3], ["id": 4]]
let numbers = dict.flatMap { $0.values } // [1, 2, 3, 4]
let chunkSize = 2
let chunks = stride(from: 0, to: numbers.count, by: chunkSize).map {
    Array(numbers[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, numbers.count)])
}
print(chunks) // [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

UPD.

I see that the `numbers` is same variable, but it can contains different values. In this case you can check the type of `numbers` and then use appropriate way to group.

```
var values: [Int] = []

if let numbers = numbers as? [String] {
    values = numbers.map { Int($0) }
} else if let numbers = numbers as? [[String, Int]] {
    values = numbers.compactMap { $0["id"] }
}
```

and then use stride on `values`:

```
let chunkSize = 2
let chunks = stride(from: 0, to: numbers.count, by: chunkSize).map {
    Array(values[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, numbers.count)])
}
print(chunks) // [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Note, that `numbers` should be a swift `Array`, not `NSMutableArray`, because `NSMutableArray` can't be subscripted by using a `CountableRange`.

Comment: Actually i have an Exclusion case in which one Array which contains group of 2 dictionaries satisfy a given condition...so i need it in the same way.

Comment: (
        {
        "facility_id" = 1;
        "options_id" = 3;
    },
        {
        "facility_id" = 3;
        "options_id" = 12;
    },
        {
        "facility_id" = 2;
        "options_id" = 7;
    },
        {
        "facility_id" = 3;
        "options_id" = 12;
    },
        {
        "facility_id" = 2;
        "options_id" = 6;
    },
        {
        "facility_id" = 1;
        "options_id" = 4;
    }
)

Comment: see how my actual array looks like this.

Comment: @NeerajSonaro, what is the issue you are seeing with this array. It looks like that will work fine with your original code in question. It shouldn't show any errors.

Comment: @NeerajSonaro, in this case change `values` like this: `values = numbers.compactMap { $0["facility_id"] }`.

Comment: @NeerajSonaro, check the datatype of `dataArray`, it may not be an array there.

Comment: @adev  ->  var dataArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray.init()

Comment: its an Array only

Comment: @pacification i want result like this

( { "facility_id" = 1; "options_id" = 3; }, { "facility_id" = 3; "options_id" = 12; }, { "facility_id" = 2; "options_id" = 7; }, { "facility_id" = 3; "options_id" = 12; }, { "facility_id" = 2; "options_id" = 6; }, { "facility_id" = 1; "options_id" = 4; } )

Comment: @pacification can you help?

Comment: @NeerajSonaro, i provide you (correct) answer, but now you asking about different question. for that purposes you should ask a new question.

Comment: @NeerajSonaro What has all this got to do with your original question? Maybe you should update the question and fully explain what your issue is including both input data and expected result

Answer (score 1):

try below solution:

```
let numbers = [["id":1],["id":2],["id":3],["id":4],["id":5],["id":6],["id":7]]//["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
let chunkSize = 2
let chunks = stride(from: 0, to: numbers.count, by: chunkSize).map  {
    Array(numbers[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, numbers.count)])
}
print("chunks :: ", chunks)
```

// prints as `[[["id": 1], ["id": 2]], [["id": 3], ["id": 4]], [["id": 5], ["id": 6]], [["id": 7]]]`

if you want only numbers, try below code:

```
let numbersDictArray = [["id":1],["id":2],["id":3],["id":4],["id":5],["id":6],["id":7]]
let numbers = numbersDictArray.flatMap { $0.values }
let chunkSize = 2
let chunks = stride(from: 0, to: numbers.count, by: chunkSize).map  {
     Array(numbers[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, numbers.count)])
}
print("chunks :: ", chunks)
```

// prints as `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7]]`