# How to split an array into multiple subarrays

Tags: arrays, swift

Let's say I have an array of many things. For example, let's go with number 1 to 100.

```
let array = Array(1 ... 100)
```

I need to split this array into multiple arrays, by length. For example, something like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], ...]
```

Basically my one-dimensional array needs to become a two-dimensional array, I need get a "grid", so to speak. I've seen many questions about spitting an array in half etc, but haven't found anything to split an array into multiple pieces, by length.

I could loop over the array, remove the first x elements, see if there is anything left, etc, but that feels very clunky. I would expect that there is an easier way to split an array like this?

Comment: That's almost what's doing that code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491685/grouping-2-dictionaries-in-to-an-array-present-in-an-array-in-swift (the current code the author had before wanting "more").

Comment: Check the second answer in that thread.

Comment: Ah thanks! Never heard of `stride` before.